# How should I respond to question on India visa application form?

Tags: visas, india

I was born in the US and moved to India when I was 3 years old.

Now I am back in the USA and my Persons of Indian Origin Card (PIO Card) has expired, so I am applying for a visa because my Overseas Citizenship of India (OCI) won't reach me in time for my travel date.

There's a question on the application:

> Have you ever visited India before?

If I tick *Yes*, it asks me for my Visa No. and place of issue; I have never visited India on a visa before.

Should I just tick "No"?

Comment: PIO? OCI? Please clarify these three letter acronyms

Comment: Never lie to immigration officials, not in filling out forms and not in person.

Comment: As an aside are you even allowed to apply for a visa if you are an OCI?

Comment: https://www.in.ckgs.us/faq/visa/general-visa-questions/11/can-i-apply-for-oci-and-visa-together#11

@DJClayworth, Yes it seems OP can apply for visa and OCI together. (Check "Can I apply for visa and OCI together question") .

OP, can you add the PIO card number (which I presume you  used to visit India) in place of Visa no.?